# 2 dice problem wrong expected value

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, dice

Suppose we have $2$ dice $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ and we want to calculate the total number of unique combinations (order doesn't matter).

$n$ = number of values of dice

$r$ = length of output

I apply my formula for repeated unique combinations $C(n+r-1,r) = \dfrac {(n+r-1)!} {(n-r)! \, r!}$ and we get by substituting:

$C(7,2)  = \dfrac {7!}{4! \, 2!}$ which is equal to $3 \times 5 \times 7$ which is $105$.However my textbook says the correct result is $21$.

Comment: Note that $C(n+r-1,r) = (n+r-1)!/(n-1)!r!$

Comment: But C(n,r) = n!/(n-r)!r! ,C is a function.

Comment: $(n + r - 1) - r = n - 1$. $4$ and $2$ add to $6$ and not $7$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the careless mistakes:

$$C(n+r-1, r)=\frac{(n+r-1)!}{\color{red}{(n-1)}!r!}$$

$$C(7,2) = \frac{7!}{\color{red}5!2!}=\frac{7\cdot 6}{2}=21$$